# Reactjs - Does @mui/material-icons slows yarn start

Tags: reactjs, google-material-icons

My package.json includes

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.1.1",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.55",
"@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
```

When I import icons in my component

```
yarn start
```

takes about 3 minutes 40 seconds to 3 minute 25 seconds.
but when I remove it

```
yarn start
```

takes 15 seconds to start.
I am still in development, so i want to know does material icons slow yarn start and what can I do to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

`@mui/icons-material` was the issue in my case.
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/